loop creation Imacros
I apologize for my English.
I have two JavaScrypt scripts in Imacros. Separately, each one executes its own loop and works without any problems.
But for the fifth day in a row I am trying to combine these two scripts into one. to automate this process. but unfortunately I am failing again and again. for this reason I started to study JavaScrypt. my head is spinning.
Script1. It works with links.
var macro;
macro =  "CODE:";
macro +=  "SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SET !ENCRYPTION NO" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "'Подключаем наш файл" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE D:\\iMacros\\Datasources\\Ok\\URLs.csv" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "'данные с нужной строки" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{i}}" + "\n";
macro +=  "URL GOTO={{!COL1}}" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "WAIT SECONDS=2" + "\n"; 

for(i=1;i<=34;i++)

{ 
iimSet("i",i)
iimPlay(macro)
}

script2 goes to the link that script1 pulled out.
var macro;
macro =  "CODE:";
macro +=  "FILTER TYPE=IMAGES STATUS=ON" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:link__91azp<SP>photo-link__79ad9<SP>__primary__91azp*     EXTRACT=HREF" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "'PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAB OPEN" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAB T=2" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "URL GOTO={{!EXTRACT}}" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "WAIT SECONDS=5" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR=* KEY=35" + "\n";
macro +=  "WAIT SECONDS=2" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAB CLOSE" + "\n"; 
for(i=1;i<=20;i++){ 
iimSet("i",i);
iimPlay(macro);
}
iimPlay(macro)
 

and this script2 visits the profiles of the members of this link.
I put 20 people.
As I said both scripts perform their functions well, but only separately. my task is to combine these two scripts into one script.
script1 pulled a link - script2 visited 20 people - script1 pulled a second link - script2 visited 20 people and so on....
I would appreciate your help.
The maximum I could come to is that script1 loads the first link of 34 links. script2 visits only 1 person out of 20 people and the cycle starts over again. that is, script1 extracts the second link and script2 visits the second person and so on. And I want everything to be cyclic. i.e. script1 extracted the first link - script2 went through 20 profiles then the cycle starts over again where script1 extracts the second link and script2 continues to visit 20 profiles and so on.....

You need two different macro var names.
You need two different index variable names.
Then move your second loop inside the first loop.
Note that I do not use iMacros, so I can't test this, but looks right.
// Script1. It works with links.
var macro1;
macro1 =  "CODE:";
macro1 +=  "SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO" + "\n"; 
macro1 +=  "SET !ENCRYPTION NO" + "\n"; 
macro1 +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n"; 
macro1 +=  "'Подключаем наш файл" + "\n"; 
macro1 +=  "SET !DATASOURCE D:\\iMacros\\Datasources\\Ok\\URLs.csv" + "\n"; 
macro1 +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1" + "\n"; 
macro1 +=  "'данные с нужной строки" + "\n"; 
macro1 +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{i}}" + "\n";
macro1 +=  "URL GOTO={{!COL1}}" + "\n"; 
macro1 +=  "WAIT SECONDS=2" + "\n"; 


// script2 goes to the link that script1 pulled out.
var macro2;
macro2 =  "CODE:";
macro2 +=  "FILTER TYPE=IMAGES STATUS=ON" + "\n"; 
macro2 +=  "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:link__91azp<SP>photo-link__79ad9<SP>__primary__91azp*     EXTRACT=HREF" + "\n"; 
macro2 +=  "'PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}" + "\n"; 
macro2 +=  "TAB OPEN" + "\n"; 
macro2 +=  "TAB T=2" + "\n"; 
macro2 +=  "URL GOTO={{!EXTRACT}}" + "\n"; 
macro2 +=  "WAIT SECONDS=5" + "\n"; 
macro2 +=  "EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR=* KEY=35" + "\n";
macro2 +=  "WAIT SECONDS=2" + "\n"; 
macro2 +=  "TAB CLOSE" + "\n"; 

for(i=1;i<=34;i++) { 
  iimSet("i",i)
  iimPlay(macro1)

  // I changed i to pos for this loop, since you are using i in the outer loop
  for(pos=1;pos<=20;pos++){ 
    iimSet("i",pos);
    iimPlay(macro2);
  }
}


Thank you so much. You managed to solve my problem.
